# javascript why 2 different object are refering to/using same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, members

I have an object definition that has an array in it. When I instantiate 2 objects and access its members both object write to the same array. I was expecting for each object to have their own array and not share the same one. It works fine for the other members of the object. Why is this and what is the correct way of doing this? Below is a sample code

```
//define simple object
var OBJ = {
  id: 0,
  arr: [0,0]
};

//instantiate objects
let obj1 = Object.create(OBJ);
let obj2 = Object.create(OBJ);

//change members value
obj1.id = 1;
obj1.arr[0]=1111;

obj2.id=2;
obj2.arr[1]=2222;

//verify changes
console.log(obj1.id);   //id = 1 as expected
console.log(obj1.arr);  //<--- expected [1111, 0000] NOT [1111, 2222]
console.log(obj2.id);   //id = 2 as expected
console.log(obj2.arr);  //<--- expected [0000, 2222] NOT [1111, 2222]
```

Comment: Any variable referencing a non-primitive - such as an object or array - are essentially references to *memory locations* where the object exists. `obj2 = obj` just gives `obj2` a reference to the same memory location.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - sorry sir, your explanation stumbles into the why, but it is not the _**reason**_ for this occurring.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That makes sense. Sooo, what is the fix? don't use an array inside an object?

Comment: @Geo - the fix is in my answer.

Comment: @Geo As I remember it is called "pass by reference", you can "google" it. If you want to create absolutely independence object, then clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve,is possible by :

```
function OBJ() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.arr = [0,0];
}

let obj1 = new OBJ();    
let obj2 = new OBJ();
```

because it creates a separate instance for each new created object i.e. each new created object has its own copy of id and arr.

---

Your approach would work fine for primitive data types,but not for non-primitive data types like Array.You are instantiating an array on the prototype without realizing that mutating that array will modify it for all instances.

**obj1** and **obj2** originally have reference to the same **id** and **arr** of the OBJ prototype.

**obj1 / obj2** has its own new copy of **id** only when **obj1.id / obj2.id** is changed,otherwise they refer to the same **id** of **OBJ**'s prototype.

Now,this behaviour is only for primitive types.
With non-primitive types i.e. Array , both **obj1** and **obj2** always refer to the same **arr** of the OBJ prototype.

Answer (score 0):

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep

should be what you want, it will copy everything recursively

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

When you use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create an new object from `OBJ`, `OBJ` becomes the prototype of the new object. All methods and properties are taken from the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), unless the object overrides them by having it's own properties with the same name. Since the `arr` is a property of `OBJ`, all objects update, and display the same array.

**Suggested Solution**

You can convert `arr` to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that will check if `arr` is a property of the current object using [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), and if not, clone the prototypes array, and then return it.

```js
//define simple object
var OBJ = {
  id: 0,
  _arr: [0, 0],
  get arr() {
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty('_arr')) this._arr = [...this._arr];
    
    return this._arr;
  }
};

//instantiate objects
let obj1 = Object.create(OBJ);
let obj2 = Object.create(OBJ);

//change members value
obj1.id = 1;
obj1.arr[0] = 1111;

obj2.id = 2;
obj2.arr[1] = 2222;

//verify changes
console.log(obj1.id); //id = 1 as expected
console.log(obj1.arr); //<--- expected [1111, 0000]

console.log(obj2.id); //id = 2 as expected
console.log(obj2.arr); //<--- expected [0000, 2222]
```